# Why expected value of g(x) given x is just g(x)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

How to prove this
$\text{E}( g(X) \mid X) = g(X)$

Comment: Where are you struggling?  What if it was $E (g (a)|X) $ ?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag (you'll have to remove an existing tag) & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: If you ***know*** that $X=2$, what values can $\exp(X)$ take?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The random variable $g(X)$ is simply a function of $X$.  If we are given the value of $X$ then we know what $g(X)$ is, namely a specific constant. Since it is constant, its expected value is also that constant.

Comment: Somehow I feel your second sentence justifies $\text{E}[ g(X) \mid X=x ] = g(x)$.  Only then would I feel comfortable with taking the next step of saying you can also take a function of a random variable.

Comment: The OP asks for a proof, this is not a proof.  This doesn't even use the definition of the conditional expectation.

Comment: I gave an explanation which states the facts as to why E(g(X)|X)=g(X).  The questioner asked why not give a mathematical proof. I presumed that people know that conditional expectation is simply the expectation when the condition is met or known to be true.